# Winforms designer load failed: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

I created a Winforms project on .NET 6 in Visual Studio 2022. I can't edit the form because the designer fails to load.

This questions has been asked number of times, but nothing worked for me.

It's an absolutely new empty Winforms project, [example is here](https://github.com/FM102DX/_illegal_characters_error_winforms_project)

I'm running Visual Studio as admin. Nothing strange is found in the Event Viewer.

The project has no nuget dependencies. Visual Studio is just installed.

Reboot doesn't help. Other guys open the designer without any problems, thus it must be a problem with my machine, but what exactly is that problem?

Here is the stack trace:

> at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
> at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
> at Microsoft.WinForms.Utilities.Shared.ShadowCacheFolder..ctor(String shadowCacheBaseDirectory, Boolean isNetCoreProject)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerLayout.d__10.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.d__21.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHostFactory.d__7.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__28.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.<>c__DisplayClass24_1.<<-ctor>b__1>d.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
> at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__26.MoveNext()

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

Comment: When I try to get your project from Github, VS gives this error: *Git failed with a fatal error. repository 'https://github.com/FM102DX/_illegal_characters_error_winforms_project/tree/main/' not found*

Comment: Mustafa Özçetin corrected the link, please try again

Comment: OK, now I can get the project from Github. Cannot reproduce your error, though. When I run the project it works without error and displays the form. Also I can edit the form.

Comment: Found that problem caused by wi32 long path switched off. Now trying to enable this option. Also some info here https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/docs/designer/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Completely enabled long path in my system, here is the guide how to do it  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later  but that didnt help (but should)

Comment: It seems you are hitting the MAX_PATH limit of 260 chars with your solution's path on your local machine. Did you try shortening your local path? Copy and test your solution to a short path, `C:\src\MyProject.sln` for example?